# Should load-acquire see store-release immediately?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

Suppose we have one simple variable(`std::atomic<int> var`) and 2 threads `T1` and `T2` and we have the following code for `T1`:

```
...
var.store(2, mem_order);
...
```

and for `T2`

```
...
var.load(mem_order)
...
```

Also let's assume that `T2`(load) executes 123ns *later in time*(later in the modification order in terms of the C++ standard) than `T1`(store).
My understanding of this situation is as follows(for different memory orders):

1. `memory_order_seq_cst`  - `T2` load is obliged to load `2`. So effectively it has to load the latest value(just as it is the case with the RMW operations)
2. `memory_order_acquire`/`memory_order_release`/`memory_order_relaxed` - `T2` is not obliged to load `2` but can load any older value with the only restriction: that value should not be older than the latest loaded by that thread. So, for example `var.load` returns `0`.

Am I right with my understanding?

**UPDATE1:**

If I'm wrong with the reasoning, please provide the text from the C++ standard which proofs it. Not just theoretical reasoning of how some architecture might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having found no arguments to prove my understanding wrong I deem it correct and my proof is as follows:

> memory_order_seq_cst - T2 load is obliged to load 2.

That's correct because all operations using `memory_order_seq_cst` should form the single total order on the atomic variable of all the memory operations.
Excerpt from the standard:

> **[29.9/3]** There shall be a single total order S on all memory_order_seq_cst
>   operations, consistent with the “happens before” order and
>   modification orders for all affected locations, such that each
>   memory_order_seq_cst operation B that loads a value from an atomic
>   object M observes one of the following values <...>

The next point of my question:

> memory_order_acquire/memory_order_release/memory_order_relaxed - T2 is
>   not obliged to load 2 but can load any older value <...>

I didn't find any evidences which might indicate that the load executed later in the modification order should see the latest value. The only points I found for the store/load operations with any memory order different from the `memory_order_seq_cst` are these:

> **[29.3/12]** Implementations should make atomic stores visible to atomic
>   loads within a reasonable amount of time.

and

> **[1.10/28]** An implementation should ensure that the last value (in modification order) assigned by an atomic or synchronization operation
>   will become visible to all other threads in a finite period of time.

So the only guarantee we have is that the variable written will be visible within some time - that's pretty reasonable guarantee but it doesn't imply immediate visibility of the previous store. And it proofs my second point.

Given all that my initial understanding was correct.

Comment: For the second case, there's no guarantee that the write will ever become visible. "should" in standardese means normative encouragement, and is not binding on implementations.

Comment: @T.C., maybe, but other statements regarding the visibility I didn't see. And providing that programs written with atomics should make sense this might be counted as the guarantee.

Comment: @T.C. Allowing any MT program to not have UB is "non binding", if you go there. If you refuse to rely on "should", you can't program, period.

Answer (score 6):

> Am I right with my understanding?

No. You misunderstand memory orders.

> let's assume that `T2`(load) executes 123ns later than `T1`(store)...

In that case, T2 will see what T1 does with any type of memory orders(moreover, this property is applied to read/write of any memory region, see e.g. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4431.pdf, 1.10, p.15). The key word in your phrase is **later**: it means that *someone else* forces ordering of these operations.

Memory orders are used for other scenario:

Lets some operation `OP1` comes in thread `T1` before store operation, `OP2`comes after it,  `OP3` comes in thread `T2` before load operation, `OP4` comes after it.

```
//T1:                         //T2:
OP1                           OP3
var.store(2, mem_order)       var.load(mem_order)
OP2                           OP4
```

Assume, that some order between `var.store()` and `var.load()` can be observed by the threads. What one can garantee about **cross threads order of other operations**?

1. If `var.store` uses `memory_order_release`, `var.load` uses `memory_order_acquire` and `var.store` is ordered **before** `var.load` (that is, load returns 2), then effect of `OP1` is ordered **before** `OP4`.

E.g., if `OP1` writes some variable var1, `OP4` reads that variable, then one can be assured that `OP4` will read what `OP1` write before. This is the most utilized case.

2. If both `var.store` and `var.load` uses `memory_order_seq_cst` and `var.store` is ordered **after** `var.load` (that is, load returns 0, which was value of variable before store), then effect of `OP2` is ordered **after** `OP3`.

This memory order is required by some tricky syncronization schemes.

3. If either `var.store` or `var.load` uses `memory_order_relaxed`, then with any order of `var.store` and `var.load` one can garantee **no order** of cross threads operations.

This memory order is used in case, when *someone else* ensure order of operations. E.g., if thread `T2` creation comes after `var.store` in `T1`, then `OP3` and `OP4` are ordered after `OP1`.

**UPDATE**: `123 ns later` implies `*someone else* force ordering` because computer's processor has no notion about universal time, and no operation has *precise moment* when it is executed. For measure time between two operations you should:

1. Observe ordering between finishing the first operation and beginning time counting operation on *some cpu*.
2. Observe ordering between beginning and finishing time counting operations.
3. Observe ordering between finishing time counting operation and start of the second operation.

Transitively, these steps make ordering between the first operation and the second one.

Comment: I know how memory order is used. The question is different. "The key word in your phrase is later: it means that someone else forces ordering of these operations." Later in my phrase means only that some time has passed. I didn't find any evidence in the standard that `load` guarantees that it will load the latest value with any memory order except default(seq. consistent). Could you please point me the clause where the standard guarantees it?

Comment: @ixSci: See updated answer about `later imply order`. As for garantee about loading the latest value, it is something we expect from any compiler/hardware. Probably, it can be found in processor's specification. Note, that this garantee is true for any memory read/write, not only for atomic types.

Comment: `Note, that this garantee is true for any memory read/write, not only for atomic types` - what about write buffers, invalidation queues and other entities hindering cache coherence? No, your statement is not true. Sorry, but I asked about rigid proofs from C++ standard, not some theoretical reasoning.

Comment: @ixSci: C++ standard doesn't define terms like `123ns later`. It operates with terms `program order` (within single thread), `happens-before` relation between operations, `modification order` of `atomic` objects and so on. See, e.g., http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4431.pdf, 1.10 "Multi-threaded executions and data races", p.p. 5,8

Comment: Yet standard explicitly says that RMW operation always use the latest value when invoked. The same is true for the seq. consistent(if I understand it right) but I didn't find any mention for any other memory orders. The concept `123ns later` is just to make sure that the operation really happens after in terms of the real life, not any software models.

Comment: `123ns later` might be treated as "later in the modification order" in terms of C++ standard.

Comment: `standard explicitly says that RMW operation always use the latest value when invoked.` - precise place in the standard, please. If `modification order` is implied by the `happens-before` order, then p.15 specifies that read of **any** (even non-atomic) object should return what has been written before. Otherwise, the only garantee about latest value is `the last value (in modification order) assigned by an atomic or
synchronization operation will become visible to all other threads in a finite period of time` (p.28). Note, that RMW operation implies `happens-before` with other RMW one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80385/discussion-between-tsyvarev-and-ixsci).

Answer (score 0):

123 nS later doesn't enforce of ordering T2 seeing the results of T1.  That's because if the physical program counter (transistors, etc.) running T2 is more than 40 Meters away from the physical program counter running T1 (large multi-core supercomputer, etc.), then the speed of light will not allow the T1 written state information to propagate that far (yet).  Similar effect if the physical memory used for the load/stores is remote by some distance to both thread processors.